# Tree structure in R

Tags: r, cart

Is there any package provides tree structure manipulation? E.g. create a tree, get child / parent, add child / siblings /, traverse, etc.

I googled and find several packages such as 'tree', however they are for classification / regression

Comment: Would a general package for graph/network analysis help? If so, you can use `igraph` or `network`.

Comment: You want to look into data.tree . It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of operation that you're looking for sounds like the behavior of a *directed graph*, specifically a *[directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)*.

As it happens, there are several packages that allow this type of manipulation-

The [gRbase](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRbase/vignettes/gRbase-graphs.pdf) package implements the functionality of several other packages, and the documentation linked above suggests [graph](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjABahUKEwi8v5GM9ezHAhXHlYgKHdJ-AWk&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bioconductor.org%2Fpackages%2Frelease%2Fbioc%2Fmanuals%2Fgraph%2Fman%2Fgraph.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH2kWKy7wqUlp_0f4-OrvSfe6S50Q&bvm=bv.102022582,d.cGU), [RBGL](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwj8ivKX9ezHAhXBXIgKHUKaDoc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bioconductor.org%2Fpackages%2Frelease%2Fbioc%2Fmanuals%2FRBGL%2Fman%2FRBGL.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFA2Kgm_GcSmlfe5kfg_qGK604O9w&bvm=bv.102022582,d.cGU), [Rgraphviz](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwi2tI6i9ezHAhUFpYgKHXJKBdA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbioconductor.org%2Fpackages%2Frelease%2Fbioc%2Fhtml%2FRgraphviz.html&usg=AFQjCNFrZHzHrkD7fV1IGEEwhcYx5W42Ug&bvm=bv.102022582,d.cGU) and [igraph](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjABahUKEwjYzr2r9ezHAhXDLogKHQ7SCAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Figraph%2Figraph.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFFOBwN0J9cSZts9WKixSmWYgag6A&bvm=bv.102022582,d.cGU).

Generally, the term "tree" in R is going to refer you to some variation of the "decision tree" machine learning algorithm, which it sounds like you inadvertently found some resources for.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout package [data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/index.html) to see if it meets your needs.  It creates trees from multiple sources (data tables, JSON, YAML), has traversing capabilities, and aggregation methods. Check the vignettes in the package for many examples.

Comment: Can you say anything more about this package & how it may resolve the OP's issue?

Comment: Yes, it turns out I am working through it's capabilities right now.  It creates trees from multiple sources (data tables, JSON, YAML), has traversing capabilities, and aggregation methods.   Check the vignettes in the package for many examples.

Comment: I don't agree with the comments. I may be l partial as I am the author of data.tree, but I think the answer answers exactly the question.